# How to change Reference image color within blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, image

i have a lot of reference images which are black and white that i want to model , i want to change their color to something like blue or white , but with only blender , how can i do that ?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import them using the function "Image as planes", then usa a node setup like this:

[image]

Don't forget to set the blend mode to "Alpha blend".
The image will be visible only in Look Dev and rendered mode.

Comment: so its not possible ?

Comment: You can render the colored image and use it as background image.

Answer (score 2):

one possibility is to use the mix rgb node like this:

[image]

[image]